# Multiple Monitors in Windows Vista Guest

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am trying to use multiple monitors inside my VMware guest to test out some multi-monitor software. This works fine in Windows XP, but doesn't work at all in Windows Vista. In the "Display" settings for the VM, I have tried "Accelerate 3D graphics" on and off, and I am forcing 4 monitors with a max resolution of 1024x768. In VMware Workstation 6.5 Windows Vista worked perfectly, but since the addition of Aero support it seems the multiple monitor support has been lost. Multiple monitor support was the primary reason I bought VMware Workstation instead of using the free alternatives, so I would really appreciate any help in restoring this functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you terminal service into the virtual machine from a physical workstation that has two monitors using the `mstsc /span` command that was introduced with MSTSC v6 then that should get you there?